# Can I get checkstyle to run when I press the Run Android Application button in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, checkstyle

I have a gradle file that includes checkstyle like so

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

check.dependsOn 'checkstyle'

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    configFile file("${project.rootDir}/config/checkstyle/xdesign_checkstyle_auto.xml")
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
    }

    classpath = files()
}
```

In this I have a task called checkstyle where I run the checkstyle plugin to check my code for problems.

I currently have my code in a state that fails the checkstyle tests. When I run `gradle build` I see that this is true.

However when I just hit the 'play' button in Android Studio to build a debug APK the check is never run and the build is successful. I expect the build to fail if there are any errors such as when I do a `gradle build`.

How can I make Android Studio run `gradle check` when I build a debug APK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make Android Studio run `gradle check`:

1. Open Menu->Run->Edit Configurations
2. Create Android Application run configuration (or use existing one).
3. Scroll down and find "Gradle-aware Make".
4. Add "Gradle-aware Make". Enter task ":<your-app-module-name>:check", e.g. for me task is `:app:check`.

In addition, you can try Android Check plugin (https://github.com/noveogroup/android-check). It has Checkstyle and PMD configurations from-the-box and automatically adds corresponding source checking to standard `check` task.

Usage:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.noveogroup.android:check:+'
        ...
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.noveogroup.android.check'
```